# How to use \underset with the iopart document class and setstack.sty

Tags: math-mode, formatting, packages

I have the following code where I am trying to use `\underset`, as defined in `setstack.sty`. However, every time I compile the code I get the error `Undefined control sequence \underset{top}{bottom}`. `setstack.sty` is in the same folder as my document. Is it as simple as I am importing `setstack.sty` wrong?

```
    %                                                                      %
%    LaTeX source code `ioplau2e.tex' used to generate `author         %
%    guidelines', the documentation explaining and demonstrating use   %
%    of the Institute of Physics Publishing LaTeX preprint files       %
%    `iopart.cls, iopart12.clo and iopart10.clo'.                      %
%                                                                      %
%    `ioplau2e.tex' itself uses LaTeX with `iopart.cls'                %
%                                                                      %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\documentclass[10pt]{iopart}
\newcommand{\gguide}{{\it Preparing graphics for IOP Publishing journals}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Packages added by Austin Downey

\usepackage[]{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs} % used for bars on tables
\usepackage{placeins}    % used to allow \floatbarrier
\usepackage{array,multirow}  % used to add lines into my tables
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{soul} % used for strike throuh in editing
\usepackage{stfloats} % used to add bp, for placing figure*
\usepackage{setstack}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

% For two-column output uncomment the next line and choose [10pt] rather than [12pt] in the \documentclass declaration
\ioptwocol

\begin{equation}
\underset{top}{bottom}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

I tried to leave as much of the preamble as possible so show the various packages I am using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `setstack` (which is an obsolete package, by the way); `iopart` isn't compatible with `amsmath`, so I cannot recommend using the class. If you are compelled to use it, you can get away with `stackrel`:

```
%                                                                      %
%    LaTeX source code `ioplau2e.tex' used to generate `author         %
%    guidelines', the documentation explaining and demonstrating use   %
%    of the Institute of Physics Publishing LaTeX preprint files       %
%    `iopart.cls, iopart12.clo and iopart10.clo'.                      %
%                                                                      %
%    `ioplau2e.tex' itself uses LaTeX with `iopart.cls'                %
%                                                                      %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\documentclass[10pt]{iopart}
\newcommand{\gguide}{{\it Preparing graphics for IOP Publishing journals}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Packages added by Austin Downey

\usepackage[]{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs} % used for bars on tables
\usepackage{placeins}    % used to allow \floatbarrier
\usepackage{array,multirow}  % used to add lines into my tables
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{soul} % used for strike throuh in editing
\usepackage{stfloats} % used to add bp, for placing figure*
%\usepackage{setstack}
\usepackage{stackrel}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

% For two-column output uncomment the next line and choose [10pt] rather than [12pt] in the \documentclass declaration
\ioptwocol

\begin{equation}
\stackrel[bottom]{top}{middle}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The key point is that you include

```
\usepackage{iopams}
```

besides

```
\usepackage{setstack}
```

Comment: Please explain better what you mean ...